# UITableview and asynchronous requests

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsurlsession

I have an issue where if a user types into the search bar too fast the program will crash with the following message

> fatal error: index out of range

referring to the line `var podInfo = podcastResults[row]` which is part of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. The search box is above a `UITableView` which is populated from the `NSURLSession` results.

Please see the code below.

```
class SearchTVC: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
  var podcastResults = [[String: String]]()
  var tempDict = [String: String]()

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    print("search being typed")

    if searchText.characters.count >= 3 {

        let searchesArray:Array = searchText.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

        //request search method to start

        search(searchesArray)
    }
}

func search(searchqueries: Array<String>){


    let URL = iTunesSearcher().searchQuery(searchqueries) //This just complies  the URL using a method in anothr class


    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(URL) {
        (data, response, error) in
        print("URL downloaded")

        //clear results and temp dict, so that new results can be displayed

        self.tempDict.removeAll()
        self.podcastResults.removeAll()

        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: URL) //urlString!
        let json = JSON(data: data!)

        for (key, subJson) in json["results"] {

            if let title = subJson["collectionCensoredName"].string {

                self.tempDict = ["title": title]

            } else { print("JSON - no title found") }

            if let feedURL = subJson["feedUrl"].string {

                self.tempDict.updateValue(feedURL, forKey: "feedURL")

            } else { print("JSON - no feedURL found") }

            if let artworkUrl60 = subJson["artworkUrl60"].string {

                self.tempDict.updateValue(artworkUrl60, forKey:"artworkURL60")

            } else { print("JSON - no artwork url found") }

            self.podcastResults.append(self.tempDict)
        }

        //Running request on main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        })
    }

    task.resume()
}

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let row = indexPath.row
    var podInfo = podcastResults[row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = podInfo["title"]
    return cell
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I just can't figure it out.

Cheers.

Michael

Comment: whats your `numberOfRows` method return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the number of rows you return in your `UITableViewDataSource` is `self.podcastResults.count`.
If so, what you need to do is turn this:

```
let row = indexPath.row
var podInfo = podcastResults[row]
cell.textLabel?.text = podInfo["title"]
```

into

```
let row = indexPath.row
if row < podcastResults.count {
    var podInfo = podcastResults[row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = podInfo["title"]
}
```

This will ensure that no matter when the cell is requested the index will never be out of bounds (and I think this happens after you remove all the elements from the array in the request handler).

Answer (score 0):

Try reloading the table when you remove all the elements from your array ie. `self.tempDict.removeAll()
 self.podcastResults.removeAll()` it seems that table is not refreshed and still shows the elements which are now actually removed.